# IE9 input/button element border color issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-9

In the site I am currently building I am having trouble getting my border colors right for `<input>` and `<button>` elements. I would like to have the top, left, and right borders to be the same color and then have the bottom border a different color. I can get the styling to work for any other element to work except for those two, and this issue only exist in IE9. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Example of my problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/NyG3x/24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting to borders separately.

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 5px solid #CE181E
```

This appears a bug in IE9. If you set the bottom border to 1px, the red border appears to show correctly. However, if you set the value to anything more than 1px, it seems to revert the `border-color` to the value of the other `border-color`.

**UPDATE**

A simple solution would be to remove the styling from the `button`, wrap the inner text of the `button` inside a `div` and style the `div`. This works in IE9 as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NyG3x/46/).

Comment: Still doesn't work... It seems like one border side color is taking precedence over the others.

Comment: I've googled and it seems a common issue. Do you have to use IE9? You could IE9 to render a page as IE8 would using a meta tag. That'll solve the issue.

Comment: This is without a doubt an IE9 bug. Setting to bottom border to 1px red, it renders it fine. Anything larger than red it reverts the colour to black.

Comment: I doubt this is a bug in IE. What does IE9's style inheritance say?

Comment: @David In F12 Developer Mode, it actually says `border-bottom-color: #ce181e;` which it is not.

Comment: From that, I think the correct border bottom color is being applied, but the button is too big (it overflows its container). What happens if you make the button vertically smaller and add `outline: 1px solid blue;"?

Comment: It's not overflowing. It's taking the colour of the other sides. The grey inside of the button is even sitting 1px below the containing element, proving it's not overflowing.

Comment: Yeah I increased, decreased, and removed the height all together and no change.

Comment: @eivers88 you seen my edit to my post? It solves the issues, although you'll need to add an extra div inside the button.

Comment: +1 for your time and solution, I think I'm going to hold off and see if anyone else has a less DOM polluting solution, thanks though!

Comment: No problem, I've done some tests and it's bugging me. I'll like to know if there's a solution for this as well!

Comment: Not being able to test this myself in IE9, I'm find it hard to understand what the solution is from what's written here. Please clarify: does setting the borders separately work, or do you need the 'Update' suggestion (which in my case is much harder as I don't have access to change the DOM)?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is more markup, but it will surely solve the issue.

Apply the 1px border as usual to the three sides, but wrap your form elements in a tag, say a div tag and apply a 5px bottom border on the div tag.

HTML would look something like this:

```
<form id="button-set-two">
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <input class="btn-style" type="submit" value="Btn1" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And CSS would look like this:

```
#button-set-two .btn-style{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:none;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    background: none;
}

#button-set-two .btn-wrapper{
    border-bottom:5px solid #CE181E;
}
```