# IE-9 not responding to ng-class changes

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

My input box looks something like this :

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="someData" ng-class="{ 'borderRed': invalid}">
```

When `$scope.invalid` is set to true, I expect the border of the inputBox to turn red. This works fine in chrome and firefox, but not in IE9.

A plnkr available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vdRIiYhFAeX6DBLMSmxs

However IE 9 doesn't open the plnkr but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Is invalid a function ?

Comment: invalid is a variable. Please check the plnkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in IE9. This post helped me find a answer [IE9 input/button element border color issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165061/ie9-input-button-element-border-color-issue)

ng-invalid is a class defined in Angular framework (angular.js)

I resolved this bug by adding the following attributes to the input box class upon error:

```
        border-bottom 1px solid red;
        border-top 1px solid red;
        border-left 1px solid red;
        border-right 1px solid red;
```

This solved the issue for me.